# saving to multiply tables php mysql

Tags: php, sql, database

I have to 2 tables and I am trying to save data to both at the same time.. Table "lyricsAuthor" contains PK(id) and table "test" contains FK(testid). 
It Works saving to both tables now, but the "testid" saves a 0, and not the last "id" from "lyricsAuthor".

I can not see what I am missing??
My current code is like this:

```
        $pdo = Database::connect(); 

        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $testid = "SELECT id FROM lyricsAuthor ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";               
        $sql = "INSERT INTO test (testid,testname) values(?, 'John Doe')";
        $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $q->execute(array($testid));

        Database::disconnect();
        header("Location: lyrics.php");
```

Comment: the value you fed inside the execute doesn't make sense, its still a literal query string and nothing else. you need to fetch the select first before getting any value from it.

Answer (score 1):

Use `mysql_insert_id` instead of `SELECT id...` to get the ID of the most recently inserted row in the current script context, otherwise you'll have concurrency issues if multiple visitors load your webpage at the same time (subtle delays in the DB will cause the IDs to be mismatched).

In PDO the method is `$link->lastInsertId();` in MySQLi it's `$link->insert_id;`

Comment: Thanks for the answers..
I am quite new to php. Maybe its a stupid question, but how do I use that in the code? Or how do I insert that?

Comment: @Axl I suggest looking at the documentation as it contains usage examples.